# Is there a jquery event for handling edits of text boxes?

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a way to bind to an event whenever the text of a text box changes.  Right now, I have something like this:

```
$("#inputPane").change(function() { alert("Changed!"); });
```

However, this only gets called when the text box loses focus.  I want to get an event whenever a new character is added, deleted, or a cut/paste occurs.

I'd prefer not to use any third party plugins for this.  Using pure jquery would be nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's an example of how to capture any change

```
$('#Textbox1, #Textbox2').each(function () {

    $(this).bind("propertychange keyup input paste", function (event) {
        alert("changed");
    });
});
```

I use this on a group of textboxes and it only fires once

Comment: This answer works the best for me since I also need to add paste to the list of events.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The best option is to use [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event.

```
$("#inputPane").keyup(function() {
    alert("Changed!");
});
```

However you should consider that it will fire whenever *ANY* key is clicked, even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, etc.

Comment: The answer I chose was slightly better because it included 'paste'.

Comment: Be careful with that. It might not work: http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html

Comment: Thanks.  I'll keep an eye on it.  My purposes are quite simple.  I just want to keep the count of the number of characters in a text box as the user types.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably need several events to cover keyed in characters, paste etc.

```
$("#inputPane").on('keyup paste click whatever', function() {
    alert("Changed!");
});
```

If for some reason it fires multiple times:

```
var fire = true;

$("#inputPane").on('keyup paste click whatever', function() {
    if (fire) {
       fire=false;            
       alert("Changed!");
    }
    setTimeout(function() {fire=true}, 200);
});
```

Comment: Then it may fire multiple times.

Comment: This is a good answer too, but I can only choose one.  I'm just learning jquery and all this has been very helpful.  Thanks.